# ActiveCell.Formula 1004 Error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("B2").Activate
ActiveCell.Formula = "=LEFT(I2,IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",I2,1)),LEN(I2),FIND(",",I2,1)-1))"
```

There are a few people who have posted solutions, but I have tried all the ones that seem relevent.

From switching between `Formula` and `FormulaR1C1` ... to using double, triple, and even quad quotes around the formula.

Anyhelp at this point would be wonderful.

Comment: The wasy way for quotes is to use the Macro Recorder to capture entering the formula manually.

Comment: In your case, with only one character, can I suggest: `"=LEFT(I2,IF(ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(44),I2,1)),LEN(I2),FIND(CHAR(44),I2,1)-1))"`

Comment: You could also simplify the formula by concatenating a comma to the end of the search cell, thereby avoiding any errors - this will give the same result - `"=LEFT(I2,FIND("","",I2&"","")-1)"`

Comment: brettdj, your solution not only solved this issue, but solved a lot of other ones I had.  Now when I run into an issue, I just use the record macro, read the code, and follow it along!  Saves soooo much time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you

```
Range("B2").Formula = "=LEFT(I2,IF(ISERROR(FIND("","",I2,1)),LEN(I2),FIND("","",I2,1)-1))"
```

If not what version of Excel are you using?